# Getting landing price from amazon API

Tags: python, amazon-mws, amazon-product-api

I've been using the Amazon Product API in Python via [this client](https://github.com/yoavaviram/python-amazon-simple-product-api).

However, I want to get the "landing price" for a given product - the price that Amazon displays prominently, the most competitive price when taking into account both the base price and delivery price. For example if a product has 2 offers such as $1 + $5 delivery vs $3 Free delivery, the landing price would be the $3 and be shown prominently by Amazon as it's the most competitive.

If I use the [OfferSummary](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/RG_OfferSummary.html) ResponseGroup of the Amazon Product API, doing `response = amazon.lookup(ItemId=asin, ResponseGroup='OfferSummary')`, then I get a response like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Item xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2013-08-01">
  <ASIN>B072KHRPLF</ASIN>
  <ParentASIN>B07CJ6DNF4</ParentASIN>
  <OfferSummary>
    <LowestNewPrice>
      <Amount>7723</Amount>
      <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
      <FormattedPrice>&#xA3;77.23</FormattedPrice>
    </LowestNewPrice>
    <TotalNew>2</TotalNew>
    <TotalUsed>0</TotalUsed>
    <TotalCollectible>0</TotalCollectible>
    <TotalRefurbished>0</TotalRefurbished>
  </OfferSummary>
</Item>
```

for [this product](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B072KHRPLF/ref=s9_acsd_zgift_hd_bw_b1vlt3P_c_x_w?pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-12&pf_rd_r=VX7B2CE4KA79T8J8B5J9&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=ded474cc-3e8d-5639-8ddd-b6a1f6a89f6c&pf_rd_i=1769797031&th=1&psc=1), which has a landing price of £92.08 Free delivery and another offer price of £77.23 + £17.50 delivery (£94.73 in total, and hence not the most competitive and not the landing price, despite having the lowest base price)

As far as I can tell I'd need to use the Amazon MWS API and call the `GetCompetitivePricingForASIN` endpoint perhaps, but I believe this needs a $40/month seller account.

Is there any other way to get the landing price? or anyway to do it via the Product API?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible from PAPI. You either need MWS API, or you can use other free/cheaper third-party alternatives if you just need the landing price.

We use the [amazon-price](https://rapidapi.com/ebappa1971/api/amazon-price) API from RapidAPI, it supports price/rating/review count fetching for up to 1000 products in a single request.